# How can I connect an Android app to Raspberry Pi, via Bluetooth, in order to send a text file of numbers?

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

I am working with an Android app in Android Studio, and a Raspberry Pi 3 operating on NOOBS. I want to have the app query the Pi for numbers from a text file, or just the entire text file if need-be.

So far, I have followed this tutorial: (http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-Using-an-App/?ALLSTEPS) for making an app that operates a LED connected to the Raspberry Pi's GPIO. I was successful, but this did not use Bluetooth. I tried it mainly to confirm I can actually do something between the Android app and the Raspberry Pi.

I then tried this tutorial: (http://www.instructables.com/id/Android-Bluetooth-Control-LED-Part-2/?ALLSTEPS) that creates an Android app to connect via bluetooth, in order to control a LED. This tutorial however, uses Arduino, not Raspberry Pi. As such, the Arduino sketch will not work on the Pi. I tried coding my own C program, that mimics what the Arduino sketch is doing, but it did not work for me. My attempt at this tutorial failed. I will post the code I tried writing below, in case someone could help me fix my C program and maybe take another stab at this one.

The code I wrote for controlling a LED on the Raspberry Pi, via Android app Bluetooth connection:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

#define LED 11 // Pin 17

void ledOn();
void ledOff();

char command[4];
char strin[4];
int ledon = 0;
int strtolVal;
int fd;
char sgc[4];
int sgci;

void ledOn() {
    digitalWrite(LED, 1);
}

void ledOff() {
    digitalWrite(LED, 0);
}

int main() {
    fd = serialOpen("/dev/rfcomm1", 115200);
    wiringPiSetup();
    pinMode(11, OUTPUT); // physical #11, GPIO #17

    while(1) {

        if(serialDataAvail(fd) > 0) {
            sgci = serialGetchar(fd);
        }

        sgci = serialGetchar(fd);
        sgc[0] = sgci + '0';

        if(strcmp(sgc, "0") == 0) {
            ledOff();
        } else if (strcmp(sgc, "1") == 0) {
            ledOn();
        }   
    } // end while loop
} // end main()
```

Controlling the LED is not my end goal, so I am less concerned that I have a working Android app to control a LED, and more concerned that I can get something working between an Android app and the Pi via Bluetooth. Thus, my new goal is to be able to display text in an Android app, that was received via Bluetooth from the Pi.

I have searched endlessly for a solution to this problem, and it's either the case that the connection is not through Bluetooth, or the app is connected to something other than the Pi. If somehow, there is something out there that does exactly what I'm searching for, then I apologize for my poor searching skills.

Comment: Only teling that it did not work out for you is not very informative. You are expected to tell exactly what should happen. And what happens or happens instead.

Comment: Why are you giving such bad info? We can do nothing with it. You are supposed to tell exactly what your code does or not does. Youwant help isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

there is another similar question I asked few minutes ago on similar topic:
[Data transfer via bluetooth between paired Android and Raspberry PI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839568/data-transfer-via-bluetooth-between-paired-android-and-raspberry-pi/39840042#39840042)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I looked through the code and I see that it can be useful for bluetooth connection establishment and communication, but I am curious what setup you have working with the app. Are you using two android devices to connect together, as in the Google example, or one android device connected to a computer like a raspberry pi?

Comment: I use two android phones or android phone and  HC05 module. The only difference is, that hc05 has different UUID

Comment: // HC-05 UUID  "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"
    public static final UUID HC_05_UUID =
            UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");