# Data transfer via bluetooth between paired Android and Raspberry PI

Tags: android, mobile, bluetooth, transfer

I am working on a project where I need to transfer data between android and raspberry pi via Bluetooth. However, I am new to this and I don't have deep understanding on what happens when two devices are paired. Based on assumption that the two devices of interest are already paired, where would the starting point be for programming for such task? I've been reading on BluetoothSocket, but I am still unsure of where to start. Can anyone help me please?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working on the same task little while ago. The point is, that in order to start sending and receiving data you have to establish connection first. There is two side- device which connects (creates socket) and the other receiving connection (bluetooth server socket), giving out connection once connection is complete. After connection is established, you should stop receiving incoming connection or attempting establishing any connections.
From implementation perspective, you should implement few threads for managing all those stages - connection thread, accept thread, communucation thread. There is a great example from Google: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat . It uses that technic. The only drawback is that it uses Handler (Android feature, allowing thereads to communicate) for informing user about Bluetooth events. I modified it a bit by introducing another thread, receiving status updates and calling methods from callback interface, feel free to use code from project: https://github.com/AlexShutov/LEDLights.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will give it a shot and let you know how what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking into this same issue, here is the reading I found on my end. I was looking to specifically code in python so that's the angle of the first one, the second is C++, but has a really thorough intro.

https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/index.html

and this one is really good too, the intro isnt too dense:

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html

The specific parts to look at involve the planning aspect. The intro of the beej programming guide shows specifically what sockets are and how they fit in a network sense. This means streaming sockets and datagram sockets. It also shows which of the sockets are used and which are availible. Chapters 1 through 3 gave me a solid enough reading basis to use the second document to determine a few things.

Chapter 2 of the MIT document goes into specific detail about each of the steps that must occur at a structural level including L2CAP + UDT, RCOMM, and whatever the stream one was. From reading these I was able to determine that the network I wanted to use was an L2CAP. I hope these help point you in the right direction though as far as what network you want to setup and what language you want to program in.

Comment: You have provided only Links to Programming Guides for Bluetooth. Add details how the OP can achieve what he needs. I don't want to downvote, but your answer is not complete.

Comment: Will do. Sorry about that.